# what are the ways to make the autorouter in eagle work faster?

Tags: eaglecad, speed, autorouter

I know one obvious way is to upgrade to a modern computer but not a lot of people can afford to do that.

What I have attempted to do to try to speed up auto-routing operation is to add lines from the restrict layer to prevent eagle from making ridiculous long-loop connections.

I have also added space to some components, but I can't add too much space since I only have so much board material.

Is there any other way I can speed up the auto router?

Comment: Turn it off and route manually?

Comment: I tried routing manually in the past and that actually takes longer, especially when trying to make the decent lines that the autorouter does, and besides, the auto-router is able to make perfect 45-degree angles.

Comment: Eagle doesn't have a manual routing mode that keeps you on 45 and 90 degree angles?

Comment: It might but manual routing will still take longer.

Comment: Mike, the solution is to turn off the autorouter. Did you put into your measure how much time it costs to do those lines in the restrict layer? When it comes to high-speed or impedance-controlled tracks, you had to route manually in any case. If you need 45° angles in manual routing, just use the _/ and \\_ track laying modes instead of direct connections. Oh, and use a reasonable grid.

Comment: It turns out routing is slightly faster if I used 10mils for all ERC settings (restrictions, wire size etc). I don't draw many restrict layer lines. I also figured out I needed to increase the rip-up depth value from the default 10 to at least 100. As for high impedance, I will use inductors. I already purchased a good 460 of them off ebay for less than $10 USD.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the solution which you already aware about - using faster PC - there's a way how to make it running faster, but it is close to manual routing.

Autorouter should router faster when you place components in convenient places of the board making autorouter's task easy, but, to do it properly, you need to have idea about how board should be routed. But if you know how it should be routed, you will be able to route manually relatively effectively and efficiently.

There're several tips setting up component layout for routing - most obvious is having `-` tracks at one level and `|` tracks at another level, having them connected through through-hole pads or vias: this can be implemented very well for set of wires having same function (e.g. address bus, data bus).

In my opinion putting restrictions on routing area should slow down the autorouting task - simply because there're more components for autorouter to consider during routing.